# How to calculate the Big 0 of a recursive function cycle of multiple methods?

Tags: algorithm, performance, recursion, big-o

How do I calculate the Big O time-complexity of the recursive functions below? I would have guessed it to be O(log(n)) because of the `F2(N/2)` call in `F1` but I'm not sure whether that is correct. How to calculate the Big O of recursive functions with multiple methods?
[image: function_image]

Comment: First of all, there is no "n" in your problem, only an "N". Be careful with your notations. Other than that, your analysis is correct; it is O(log(N)). But note that "being O(log(N))" only expresses a majoration; the final `return N` statement in F2 hints that on some particular inputs, the complexity might be lower than log(N). Finally, note that an input number N is expressed as a sequence of bits; we usually like to express complexities as a function of the size of the input, and not as a function of the number represented by the input.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: for simplicity I'll analyze only positive values of `N`. Analysis for the negative values is similar and dependent of the definition of `%` operation for negative operands.

The only interesting input of `F1` is `N = 4k + 3`, where `k` is any non-negative integer. For any other input it's easy to show that F2 returns immediately, thus the overall time is `O(1)`.

Let's trace the call of `F1(4k + 3)`:

```
F1(4k + 3)
 F1(4k + 2)
    F2(2k + 1)
```

Now, if `(2k + 1) % 4` equals 3, recursion continues, otherwise it terminates immediately. Let's check two scenarios:

- if `k` is even: `(2k + 1) = 4(k/2) + 1`; the modulo 4 is `1`, recursion terminates
- if `k` is odd: `(2k + 1) = 4((k-1)/2) + 2 + 1 = 4((k-1)/2) + 3`: recursion continues, calling `F1(4(k-1)/2 + 3)`

`F1` is called again with `k₁ = (k-1)/2`. For recursion to continue, `k₁` must be also odd, which is possible, when `(k-1)` is not divisible by 4. In other words, for inputs `N=g(x)`, where `g(0)=1;  g(x)=g(x-1)*2 + 1` the calculation of `F1(N)` will take `O(log(N))` time, which allows to establish the upper bound.

---

Here is the plot of F1 and F2 steps for given input N:

[image: F1 and F2 steps for given input N]